# Remove Unwanted Gap from PHP-Generated URL

Tags: php, html

This script sends instructions to delete a user from a database when a php-generated link is clicked.

```
<?php

    $user = $_GET['user'];
    $zip = $_GET['zip'];  

    $url = "<p>http://domain.org/remove.php?do=delete";
    $url .= "&removeid=".$user."&rcrd=".$zip."</p>"; 
    echo $url;

?>
```

But the generated link has an unwanted space after "&removeid=" producing the following:

http://domain.org/remove.php?do=delete&removeid= 160294&rcrd=41233

The link is, therefore, unclickable.

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: PHP doesn't insert spaces. If you get a space in there, you're SENDING a space in that `user` query parameter.

Comment: I thought that this might be the case, but I checked for an unintentionally inserted space before posting. There wasn't one to be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the function trim - http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

`trim($user);`

Comment: Simple, but precisely what was needed.  Many thanks for averting a brewing headache.